# Invisible Earbuds

Tags: lm386

I just made a pair of invisible earbuds using this guide http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-Your-Invisible-Earphones/?ALLSTEPS everything works fine using 6mm x 6mm magnets that sit in my outer ear and not near the ear drum. I use it to listen to music and it works pretty well, but when i'm in a public place it's hard to hear it. Would anyone have an idea on how to make it louder? The coil I am using is 70 turns of enameled magnet wire and I am using a prebuilt LM386. I am also using a battery pack that outputs 11.2v to it.

This is what the LM386 that I bought looks like [image: LM386]

Comment: A diagram would be of great help to us. Also you should understand that the LM386 is not a powerhouse. At some volume level either the earpiece or the LM386 is going to distort the sound. If maximum volume is not yet causing distortion, maybe some resistor values can be adjusted.

Comment: An inductive earpiece, like a regular one, is limited by how far the diaphragm can move for the power its given...

Answer (score 3):

The audio fidelity of those things must be terrible! There are all kinds of effects that are going to roll off the high frequencies on you. I guess you have to equalize the heck out of the signal to compensate.

Anyway, to get more sound, you need to increase the motion of the magnets. To increase the motion, you need a stronger field. The strength of the field is going to depend on both the construction of the coil and the capabilities of the driver.

Addressing the coil first — it may seem counterintuitive, but if you're driving the coil with a *voltage source*, and ignoring resistive losses for the moment, you want fewer turns in the coil rather than more. The issue is that the field strength is directly proportional to the number of turns *for a given current*. However, the inductance is proportional to the square of the number of turns, and the current is inversely proportional to the inductance when the voltage is held constant. This means that the total field is inversely proportional to the number of turns — at least until you hit the maximum current that the driver can supply.

Now let's look at the resistance of the coil, which is also directly proportional to the number of turns. If the resistance is significantly less than the inductive impedance, you can ignore it. Let's look at some numbers. You didn't specify the gauge of your wire, so I'll assume AWG30 as a starting point. The coil has to be big enough to slip over your head, so the circumference needs to be something over 2 feet — let's call it 70 cm. Therefore, with 70 turns, you have a total resistance of

$$330 \frac{m\Omega}{m} \cdot 0.7 \frac{m}{turn} \cdot 70 turns = 16 \Omega$$

The inductance is going to be on the order of

$$\frac{a^2 n^2}{9a+10b} = \frac{4.5^2\cdot 70^2}{9\cdot 4.5 + 10\cdot 0.25} = 2.3 mH $$

This will have an impedance of about 140 Ω @ 10 kHz, 14 Ω @ 1000 Hz and 1.4 Ω @ 100 Hz. Clearly, the inductive impedance dominates over 1000 Hz, and the resistance dominates at lower frequencies. So at lower frequencies, a constant-voltage source will drive a constant current. In this regime of operation, changing the number of turns *has no effect*, since any increase in the field strength due to having more turns is directly offset by the corresponding decrease in current.

Therefore, it makes a lot more sense to focus on your driver circuit. An LM386 is going to be rather limited in this kind of application. For several reasons, it would be far better to drive the coil with a *current source* rather than a voltage source. Most of the inductive and resistive effects could then be ignored, and you could directly control the volume by controlling the current. However, such a driver would require rather high voltages, especially at higher frequencies.

You might take a look at the [Howland current source](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474a/snoa474a.pdf), which can drive moderately high currents with low overhead.

Comment: I'm new to this so forgive me if I misunderstand. The coil is roughly 7.5 feet in diameter using 32 AWG magnet wire, 70 turns. So less coil would be better to reach the magnet in my ear and would you be able to suggest something that I could possibly buy to replace the LM386 to make it louder? Also the sound quality is actually not that bad, if a pair of earbuds were 10/10 these would be 7/10 or 8/10 imo

Comment: 7.5 feet? Really? I guess you aren't wearng it as a necklace as described in the link. How do you use it in a public place? AWG 32 has a resistance of 0.525 ohms/meter, so you're looking at a total resistance of about 260 ohms. This is preventing the LM386 from delivering any significant current. You should make a new coil using just 14 turns of AWG 26 wire, which will bring the resistance down to about 13 ohms, and reduce the inductance to a value that gives you roughly the same L/R cutoff frequency. This will allow the LM386 to deliver 20x the current and about 4x the field strength.

Comment: @DaveTweed  He must mean 7.5 inches diameter.  Do you think?

Comment: @HandyHowie: No, I doubt it. First of all, "inches" and "feet" are spelled very differently -- it isn't like the confusion between `"` and `'`. Secondly, it would be too small. A 7.5-inch coil certainly wouldn't fit over *my* head.

Comment: Yeah 7.5 inches in diameter barely fits over my head. So get 26 AWG magnet wire and make a new coil with 14 turns and it would preform better?

Comment: Well, no -- that calculation was for 7.5 feet. If it's really 7.5 inches, I'll have to work through the numbers again. Why did you say "feet" the first time?

Comment: Woops, my mistake. Sorry about that, but yeah I ment 7.5 inches